# Why does my python graph class calculate the max degree incorrectly?

Tags: python, data-structures, graph-theory

I am trying to calculate the max and min degrees of my Graph class in python and here is my code:

```
class Graph():
    def __init__(self, graph = None):
        if graph == None:
            graph = {}
        self.graph = graph
    
    def degree(self, node):
        deg =  len(self.graph[node])
        if node in self.graph[node]:
            deg += 1
        return deg

    def maxd(self):
        max = 0
        for node in self.graph:
            degree = self.degree(node)
            if degree > max:
                max = degree
        return max

    def mind(self):
        min = 10000000000
        for node in self.graph:
            nodedeg = self.degree(node)
            if nodedeg < min:
                min = nodedeg
        return min






graph = { "a" : {"c"},
          "b" : {"c", "e"},
          "c" : {"a", "b", "d", "e"},
          "d" : {"c"},
          "e" : {"c", "b"},
          "f" : {'c'}
        }

g = Graph(graph)

print("max:", g.maxd())
print("min:", g.mind())
```

```
max: 4
min: 1
```

the max is supposed to be 5 and I cannot figure out why it's returning 4.

Comment: For which node did you expect `degree` to return 5?

Comment: You only calculate the out-degree. You need a system to calculate the in-degree (and add the two)

Comment: `min = 10000000000` is troublesome. It's better to use `math.inf` (don't forget `import math`)

Comment: `max` and `min` are builtin keywords in Python.  Avoid using them for variable names.  You could end up redefining a function...

Comment: @RufusVS Unless you plan to use the built-in functions `max` or `min` in a given scope, rebinding the name is harmless.

Comment: @chepner The fact that you CAN do something doesn't mean you SHOULD do something.  Especially with larger code bases and multiple developers.  Not mandatory, but advisable.  I'd consider it bad practice, personally.

Comment: This is more of a comment on the SO community's obsession with pointing out every single instance of overriding a built-in name, even when it has nothing to do with the question being asked. (And they are *not* keywords, just pre-defined names. `if`, `for`, etc, are keywords: you *can't* use them as variable names.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the out-degree and the in-degree to get the degree of a node.

Here is an implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Graph():
    def __init__(self, graph=None):
        if graph == None:
            graph = {}
        self.graph = graph
        self.out_degree = defaultdict(int)
        self.in_degree = defaultdict(int)
        self.degree = defaultdict(int)

        for n in graph:
            self.out_degree[n] += 1
            for n2 in graph[n]:
                self.in_degree[n2] += 1

        for n in graph:
            self.degree[n] = self.out_degree[n] + self.in_degree[n]

    def degree(self, node):
        return self.degree[node]

    def maxd(self):
        return max(self.degree.values())

    def mind(self):
        return min(self.degree.values())


graph = {"a": {"c"},
         "b": {"c", "e"},
         "c": {"a", "b", "d", "e"},
         "d": {"c"},
         "e": {"c", "b"},
         "f": {'c'}
         }

g = Graph(graph)

print("max:", g.maxd())
print("min:", g.mind())
```

Outputs:

```
max: 6
min: 1
```

(the max degree is 6, not 5)

If you need to make your graph modifiable (adding nodes/edges) then you need to think about how you can modify the dictionaries that hold the node degrees, or use a different data structure.

Some additional points:

- You shouldnt use the built-in function names min and max for variables
- You should use `float("inf")` to get the maximum number:

```
min = -float("inf")
or
min = float("-inf")
and
max = float("inf")
```